# How can I use the Facebook Credit Api to reward an user with credits?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

I want to deposit Facebook credits on other users accounts. Is there a way to do that with the Facebook Credits Api?

It could be in a direct way or as a gift card.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do something like this nor does make sense. Facebook Credits are a centralized currency that is purchased with real world currencies and are valid across the Facebook platform for any app that accepts them. Were something like this supported, one could create an app to grant themselves or others credits that could be spent elsewhere on the platform. Since Facebook pays out real money to developers of apps where credits are spent, this would be equivalent of creating money out of nothing, which is bad for hopefully obvious reasons.

If your application supports the concept of virtual goods that are purchased with Facebook Credits, you could reward your users with those items instead.